# Adding all users SID's from Active Directory in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have an issue not able to add all Sid's to my current loop. Everything else is working as I expected. I just need help adding in my code to add the SID for each user my code is displaying. The SID will now show.

new error message:
[image]

Here is my current code:

```
 namespace ActiveDirectoryDisplayNamesApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "nor-amcoldcorp.local"))
            {
                using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
                {
                    foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                        var sidByte = ObjectToByteArray(de.Properties["objectSId"].Value);
                        Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value);
                        Console.WriteLine("Last Name : " + de.Properties["sn"].Value);
                        Console.WriteLine("SAM account name   : " + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value);
                        Console.WriteLine("User principal name: " + de.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value);
                        Console.WriteLine("Object Sid: " + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sidByte)); //Here is the changement
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static public byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }






    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`de.Properties["objectSid"].value` returns a Byte [] array, to view the SID you will need to parse this into a string to get the functionality you are looking for. A good post on how to do that can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/3688/how-to-get-user-sid-using-directoryservices-classe).

Below is the function you will need to convert the array into a usable string:

```
public static string ConvertByteToStringSid(Byte[] sidBytes)
{
    StringBuilder strSid = new StringBuilder();
    strSid.Append("S-");
    try
    {
        // Add SID revision.
        strSid.Append(sidBytes[0].ToString());
        // Next six bytes are SID authority value.
        if (sidBytes[6] != 0 || sidBytes[5] != 0)
        {
            string strAuth = String.Format
                ("0x{0:2x}{1:2x}{2:2x}{3:2x}{4:2x}{5:2x}",
                (Int16)sidBytes[1],
                (Int16)sidBytes[2],
                (Int16)sidBytes[3],
                (Int16)sidBytes[4],
                (Int16)sidBytes[5],
                (Int16)sidBytes[6]);
            strSid.Append("-");
            strSid.Append(strAuth);
        }
        else
        {
            Int64 iVal = (Int32)(sidBytes[1]) +
                (Int32)(sidBytes[2] << 8) +
                (Int32)(sidBytes[3] << 16) +
                (Int32)(sidBytes[4] << 24);
            strSid.Append("-");
            strSid.Append(iVal.ToString());

        // Get sub authority count...
        int iSubCount = Convert.ToInt32(sidBytes[7]);
        int idxAuth = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < iSubCount; i++)
        {
            idxAuth = 8 + i * 4;
            UInt32 iSubAuth = BitConverter.ToUInt32(sidBytes, idxAuth);
            strSid.Append("-");
            strSid.Append(iSubAuth.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return strSid.ToString();
}
```

And here is what you will need to call the function:

```
System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection coll = de.Properties;
object obVal = coll["objectSid"].Value;
string yourSID;
if (null != obVal)
{
    yourSID = ConvertByteToStringSid((Byte[])obVal);
}
```

Comment: now I am getting a weird message for SID, I added the new img in the first post obove

Comment: I don't know if you tried the method in the post I linked, but I tried it and had the SID printing out from the DirectoryEntry properties in about 5 minutes - tested and works perfectly.

Comment: that new update worked, thanks much. Now I get the correct SID of every user.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :

Declare this function :

```
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null)
            return null;

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Than do this :

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(de.Properties["objectSid"].value);
sidByte= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

Console.WriteLine("Object Sid: " + sidByte ); //Here is the changement
```

Or you try this approcah (if the first one didn't work)  but keep the first function that will convert your byte object to byte :

Declare a function

```
static string BytesToStringConverted(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Than call it like that :

```
Console.WriteLine("Object Sid: " +BytesToStringConverted (sidByte)
```

Comment: Hello @napi15, I tried and didn't work I got this system.byte[]. Didn't show the actual Sid of each user.

Comment: thanks I will try it and let you know if that worked or not, thanks.

Comment: Hello @napi15, in both solutions you added. I am getting overload method error what are you missing?

Comment: I will add the error I am getting in my first post with an image

Comment: @AndresBryan29 Try what I have edited and let me know

Comment: Hello guys someone has a solution on this?

Comment: I tried that but still not working look at my image above now I was getting that message.

Comment: @AndresBryan29 It's not an error , you need to change the output format to UTF8 , I have made an edit , Change it to   `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sidByte);` instead of `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(sidByte);`  I'm pretty sure now it will work :) tell me what happens

Comment: I tried that new change you made, and still getting the result: Object Sid:     ????                     I?%vxT???   .  . Which makes no sense.

Comment: the error is the same as the image I posted above as you can see has spaces and garbage results

Comment: @AndresBryan29 See my changement and let me know

Answer (score 0):

There is already a dedicated Sid class that you can use for decoding Sid data.

```
var sidBytes = (byte[])de.Properties["objectSId"].Value;
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(sidBytes ,0);
string strSid = sid.Value;//Something like S-1-5-21..
```

.

Answer (score 0):

1. For hexadecimal form, it should be: `string strAuth = String.Format("0x{0:x2}{1:x2}{2:x2}{3:x2}{4:x2}{5:x2}",`
2. For .NET 5, `SecurityIdentifier` only available on Windows.
   https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6bc6560e51d1cf58b54561f7be44801864479b8d/src/libraries/System.Security.Principal.Windows/src/System/Security/Principal/SID.cs#L403-L478
3. Found few bugs from the original

> https://www.codeproject.com/articles/3688/how-to-get-user-sid-using-directoryservices-classe
>
> public static string ConvertByteToStringSid(Byte[] sidBytes)

- hexadecimal conversion (Wrong `"0x{0:2x}{1:2x}{2:2x}{3:2x}{4:2x}{5:2x}"`, right: `"0x{0:x2}{1:x2}{2:x2}{3:x2}{4:x2}{5:x2}"`)
- Sub Authority Count at the second byte, not the 8th byte (Wrong `Convert.ToInt32(sidBytes[7])`, right: `Convert.ToInt32(sidBytes[1])`)

I have followed the original implementation and compare with the result from class `SecurityIdentifier`, also consider the comment:

> SID decoding is wrong Pin
>
> Hi there,
> I think your SID decoding is wrong. The number of sub authorities is the 2nd byte in the SID byte array, not the 8th, and the main authority has its bytes stored in the other order from the one you're reading in.

I'd like to share a better version, can be found at:
https://gist.github.com/thohng/8820153f7d1e107b6619b34fd765f887:

```
public static string ConvertByteToStringSid(byte[] sidBytes)
{
    if (sidBytes == null || sidBytes.Length < 8 ||
        sidBytes.Length > 68)   // maximum 15 sub authorities
        return string.Empty;

    var span = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(sidBytes);

    var strSid = new StringBuilder("S-");

    // Add SID revision.
    strSid.Append(span[0]);

    // Get sub authority count...
    var subAuthoritiesLength = Convert.ToInt32(span[1]);
    if (sidBytes.Length != 8 + subAuthoritiesLength * 4)
        return string.Empty;

    long identifierAuthority =
        (((long)span[2]) << 40) +
        (((long)span[3]) << 32) +
        (((long)span[4]) << 24) +
        (((long)span[5]) << 16) +
        (((long)span[6]) << 8) +
        span[7];
    strSid.Append('-');
    strSid.Append(identifierAuthority);

    span = span[8..];

    for (int i = 0; i < subAuthoritiesLength; i++, span = span[4..])
    {
        strSid.Append('-');
        strSid.Append(BitConverter.ToUInt32(span.Slice(0, 4)));
    }

    return strSid.ToString();
}
```

And unit tests:

```
private static Func<byte[], string> GetConvertByteToStringSidService() => LdapHelper.ConvertByteToStringSid;

[Fact]
public void ConvertByteToStringSid_Builtin()
{
    var service = GetConvertByteToStringSidService();
    var sid = new byte[] { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 32, 0, 0, 0, 39, 2, 0, 0 };
    var result = service(sid);
    Assert.Equal("S-1-5-32-551", result);
}

[Fact]
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public void ConvertByteToStringSid_Builtin_Windows()
{
    var sid = new byte[] { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 32, 0, 0, 0, 39, 2, 0, 0 };
    var s2 = new SecurityIdentifier(sid, 0);
    Assert.Equal("S-1-5-32-551", s2.ToString());
}

[Fact]
public void ConvertByteToStringSid_Malformed()
{
    var service = GetConvertByteToStringSidService();

    var sid1 = new byte[] { 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0, 222, 206, 60, 4, 227, 115, 59, 3, 168, 94, 83, 2, 1, 4, 0, 0, 1 };
    var result1 = service(sid1);
    Assert.Equal("", result1);

    var sid2 = new byte[] { 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0, 222, 206, 60, 4, 227, 115, 59, 3, 168, 94, 83, 2, 1, 4, 0 };
    var result2 = service(sid2);
    Assert.Equal("", result2);

    var sid3 = new byte[] { 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0, 222, 206, 60, 4, 227, 115, 59, 3, 168, 94, 83, 2, 1, 4, 0, 0 };
    var result3 = service(sid3);
    Assert.Equal("", result3);
}

[Fact]
public void ConvertByteToStringSid_Max()
{
    var service = GetConvertByteToStringSidService();

    var sid = new byte[] { 1, 1, 255, 254, 253, 252, 0, 0, 251, 250, 249, 248 };
    var result = service(sid);
    Assert.Equal("S-1-281470647926784-4177132283", result);

    var sid2 = new byte[] { 1, 5, 136, 0, 44, 89, 0xFE, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0, 222, 206, 60, 4, 227, 115, 59, 3, 168, 94, 83, 2, 1, 4, 0, 0 };
    var result2 = service(sid2);
    Assert.Equal("S-1-149534325472773-21-71093982-54227939-39018152-1025", result2);
}

[Fact]
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public void ConvertByteToStringSid_Max_Windows()
{
    var sid = new byte[] { 1, 1, 255, 254, 253, 252, 0, 0, 251, 250, 249, 248 };
    var s1 = new SecurityIdentifier(sid, 0);
    Assert.Equal("S-1-281470647926784-4177132283", s1.ToString());

    var sid2 = new byte[] { 1, 5, 136, 0, 44, 89, 0xFE, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0, 222, 206, 60, 4, 227, 115, 59, 3, 168, 94, 83, 2, 1, 4, 0, 0 };
    var s2 = new SecurityIdentifier(sid2, 0);
    Assert.Equal("S-1-149534325472773-21-71093982-54227939-39018152-1025", s2.ToString());
}

[Fact]
public void ConvertByteToStringSid_NullEmpty()
{
    var service = GetConvertByteToStringSidService();

    var sid1 = Array.Empty<byte>();
    var result1 = service(sid1);
    Assert.Equal("", result1);

    var result2 = service(null);
    Assert.Equal("", result2);
}

[Fact]
public void ConvertByteToStringSid_Success()
{
    var service = GetConvertByteToStringSidService();
    var sid = new byte[] { 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0, 222, 206, 60, 4, 227, 115, 59, 3, 168, 94, 83, 2, 1, 4, 0, 0 };
    var result = service(sid);
    Assert.Equal("S-1-5-21-71093982-54227939-39018152-1025", result);
}

[Fact]
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public void ConvertByteToStringSid_Windows()
{
    var sid = new byte[] { 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0, 222, 206, 60, 4, 227, 115, 59, 3, 168, 94, 83, 2, 1, 4, 0, 0 };
    var s1 = new SecurityIdentifier(sid, 0);
    Assert.Equal("S-1-5-21-71093982-54227939-39018152-1025", s1.ToString());
}
```